# Logging dropped events due to watermark in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Is it possible to log the dropped events due to watermark (events came later than the set value in watermark) in apache spark structured stream? Is there any listener interface exposed to the developers to get hold of the dropped events?